# Can't install modules in Drupal 8 Ubuntu - Should I change owner?

Tags: 8, files

Its not the first time I install Drupal 8 on Ubuntu 15.10 (which I'm very new to) but it is indeed the first time when I can't install modules at it.

[image]

I ran the error at Google and [After reading this document](https://www.drupal.org/node/1380406) regarding to a similar problem in Drupal 7, and a few other docs, It seems I should do in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R www-data sites
```

Since I am new to Linux and I also know that Drupal 8's folder hierarchy has been changed a bit, and I'm not sure if its the right move (I'm afraid to make mess); Thus, I dedicate this question to senior developers which are also Linux veterans...

Comment: Yep, Drupal's folder hierarchy has changed. Modules are no longer kept in the sites folder. They're in the root directory of the Drupal install in a folder called "modules". I haven't had to change the owner of my modules directory to install modules, but I do it through [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush). Does the directory have write permissions? Try doing `sudo chmod 755 modules`

Comment: Tried that + restarting the server - Didn't work :\ The module folder permissions are 755 and it's owner is benwork (my user). You might have any other advice for me?

Comment: The owner needs to be the web server user (www-data). It's the web server that's trying to write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the folder where you installed Drupal 8. Ex:

```
cd /var/www/drupal
```

In you case, it looks like it's:

```
cd /var/www/html/benia
```

then

```
sudo chown www-data -R modules
```

Now try installing again.

To prevent other conflict, I would www-data all of your Drupal

```
cd /var/www/html/

sudo chown www-data -R benia
```

Comment: This advice is only for developing sites. See answer from Eyal. Don't do this in production. When all php files are owned by www-data, they are not protected against manipulation when there is a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the site on a developer machine then changing the owner (and permissions) is not that harmful (as your IP is not public knowledge).

However if this is your production (/staging/QA/whatever) server you should keep the permissions as they were.

#### Sugestion:

Download contributed modules and themes via Drush, Drupal console or GIT.
*With command line you can always sudo the permissions away* :)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to use Drush and Composer to install modules. They minimize your chances of messing up. To download Composer go to getcomposer.org To download drush type: 
`composer global install drush/drush` 
Navigate to your Drupal 8 installation's modules folder by typing: 
 `cd /var/www/html/benia/modules` 
then 
`drush dl module_name` 
Navigate into the module's directory 
`cd module_name` 
Install dependencies of the module by typing: 
`composer install` 
Finally enable the module by typing: 
`drush en module_name`